# how i solve this poblem ,kindly help me this is a code here

Tags: visual-c++, compiler-errors, runtime-error

I am beginner i am trying to solve this problem
I have a problem in my this code.it give me the 'runtime error' kindly help me to resolve it.my code is here:

```
int sum(int num1,int num2) {
    return num1+num2;
}
int sum(int num1,int num2, int num3) {
   return num1+num2+num3;
}
```

Comment: This piece of code looks OK. To the extent there is a problem, it lies in the code not shown. For further assistance, prepare a [mcve].